# Terraform-AWS IAM role attach managed policy to role only if it isn't attached already

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I am attaching few managed policies (existing) to IAM role (existing). I am attaching the policies to the role by aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "role_logscreate" {
  role       = data.aws_iam_role.qrm_role_ASM_access.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${local.account_id}:policy/pB-CloudWatchLogsCreate"   
}
```

I want to add a "guard condition" that attach the policy only if it is not already attached to the Role.
Is it possible in terraform.12?

Update @marcin: we are using a Teamcity pipeline for 1-click deployment of the terraform resources. most or the time we are removing the 'all-resources' and that time we de-attach these policies as well from the role. but some times the cherry-pick approach is used and IAM is not part of that. so, there is a possibility that IAM Role still have those policies and it is difficult for TC to detect these changes. so, I want to add the guard condition in my Terraform code. "Attach only if not already attached to IAMRole". hope, there is complete context and clarity why I want to add these guard conditions.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you want to achieve? If your role already has a given policy attached, terraform will not add it second time. So you don't need to check anything.

Comment: ...and even if the state does now already show the policy as attached, the AWS API would error on this request and not attempt it.

Comment: yes, the AWS API will through the error, and my Teamcity Pipeline will fail. It better to have a guard check instead of leaving it for failure condition.